# How can I get continuous motion in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
def function():

    import pygame
    import time
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()

    Width = 272
    Height = 552

    white = 255,255,255
    blue = 0,255,255
    red = 255,0,0

    Left_Rect = pygame.Rect(0,452,135,100)
    Right_Rect = pygame.Rect(137,452,135,100)

    Location = 136

    WaterLevel = 452
    Depth = 100

    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 30

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Width,Height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('boat game')

    stop = False

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    while not stop:

####### CONTROLLES ####################################################

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Left_Rect)

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Right_Rect)


####### BOAT #########################################################
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (Location,WaterLevel-20,40,20))

####### WATER ########################################################        
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,blue,(0,WaterLevel,272,Depth))

        WaterLevel -= 1
        Depth += 1


######################################################################

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            print event

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                is_Left = Left_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                if is_Left == 1:
                    Location -= 5

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                is_Right = Right_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                if is_Right == 1:
                    Location += 5

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                stop = True
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

function()
```

I have a blue rectangle that rises up the screen, an a red rectangle that sits on top of the rising blue rectangle. put two boxes on the bottom left and right corners and when they are clicked the red box move horizontally left or right. How can I make it so I can hold down the mouse over one of those boxes and the rectangle will keep moving until I let Go

Comment: `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` only happens when the mouse if first clicked, you can check whether the button is still held down with `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`- see the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **many different** approaches for that problem. :)

A very simple and quick and dirty method is to

- **set one of two global variables called `is_Left` and `is_Right`** each time a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs *and* the respective `.collidepoint()` method returns `true`
- **reset both variables** when a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` is detected.

Your updated code for this approach:

```
#your original code

#declare global variables is_Left and is_Right
is_Left = False
is_Right = False

while not stop:
    #draw controls, boat and water
    #increment WaterLevel and Depth 

    #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #detect MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event and collision
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            is_Left = Left_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            is_Right = Right_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            #reset is_Left and is_Right
            is_Left = False
            is_Right = False            

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    #change Location
    if is_Left:
        Location -= 5
    elif is_Right:
        Location += 5

    CLOCK.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Another method is, as Marius already mentioned, to **use the [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) function** of PyGames mouse module **to get the state of the mouse buttons**.

This function returns a `tupel` of three boolean values representing the state of **all** mouse buttons. In your case we only need the **first value** which represents the state of the **left mouse button**.

We call `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]` **inside the main game loop** to get the state of the **left mouse button** and check at the same time if the respective `.collidepoint()` method returns `true`:

```
#your original code

while not stop:
    #draw controls, boat and water
    #increment WaterLevel and Depth 

    #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    #get state of left mouse button 
    isPressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

    #change location
    if ispressed and Left_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        Location -= 5
    elif ispressed and Right_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        Location += 5  

    CLOCK.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()

    CLOCK.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

In personally prefer the **second variant**, because we don´t need any extra global variables (`is_Left`, `is_Right`).

I hope this helps :)